# how do I use SetWindowPos move a designated window not the console window in c

Tags: c

I can't move my window whether it's on top or not.
But i tried the same code successfully moved the console window.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<Windows.h>

int main()
{
    HWND MyWindow,Desktop;
    RECT DeskSize,MWSize;
    int MWPosX, MWPosY,MWWidth,MWHeight;
    if (IsIconic(MyWindow))
    {
        printf("2\n");
        OpenIcon(MyWindow);
    }
    //get my window size
    MyWindow = FindWindowA(NULL, "MyWindow");
    //I use GetForegroundWindow() to get the console window not FindWindowA
    //SetForegroundWindow(MyWindow);
    //MyWindow= GetForegroundWindow();
    GetWindowRect(MyWindow, &MWSize);
    MWWidth = MWSize.right - MWSize.left;
    MWHeight = MWSize.bottom - MWSize.top;
    //get my desktop size
    Desktop = GetDesktopWindow();
    GetWindowRect(Desktop, &DeskSize);
    //move
    MWPosX = ((DeskSize.right - DeskSize.left) / 2 - MWWidth / 2);
    MWPosY = ((DeskSize.bottom - DeskSize.top) / 2 - MWHeight / 2);
    SetWindowPos(MyWindow, HWND_TOP, MWPosX, MWPosY, MWWidth, MWHeight, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Question update

The problem inexplicably disappeared.
But SetForegroundWindow() can`t works fine for my windows sometimes.
When I minimize my window , IsIconic() is not success judgment and the window is not brought to the foreground after the function is executed.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Just about all functions you call *can* fail, but you don't seem to check for that. If you add checks for success or failure, what does that tell you?

Comment: I added a BOOL variable to check if the function was successful, I found that the function call succeeds for the console window, but still fails for one of the other windows,why

Comment: If a function fails, check `GetLastError` to get the error code.

Comment: He returned ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED but this is because I did not use the administrator to start, when I use the administrator to start he returned ERROR_SUCCESS, which means that the function was successfully executed, but it did not achieve the expected effect.I removed these two lines while testing.SetForegroundWindow(MyWindow);
    MyWindow= GetForegroundWindow();

Answer (score 0):

Ok,The problem has been solved because of `HWND_TOPMOST`.I think the reason for all the problems is because the window handle I want to get is automatically deactivated when minimized.So when using `SetWindowPos()` to bring the window to the top, use `HWND_TOPMOST`